# How to integrate gamma function

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, gamma-function

Can anyone tell me how can I integrate this function ?

$\int_0^\infty x \frac{\Gamma(3\alpha) }{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(2\alpha)} x^{(\alpha -1)} (1-x)^{2\alpha-1} \, dx,  \alpha>0$

Comment: The gamma functions are just constants so you can pull them out of the integral.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, with no information or context. This does not match many users' [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement), and may attract downvotes or be put on hold. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Briefly: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Agree with mlc. Here I think the best answer is a pointer to do some research. If you look up Beta function, it is a special function involving this integral. It has a formula in terms of the Gamma function (implied by GNU supporter's answer). Will not be hard to find a derivation of this formula in one resource or another.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
& \int_0^\infty x \frac{\Gamma(3\alpha) }{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(2\alpha)} x^{(\alpha -1)} (1-x)^{2\alpha-1} \, dx \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(3\alpha) } {\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(2\alpha)} \int_0^\infty
x^{\alpha} (1-x)^{2\alpha-1} \, dx \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(3\alpha) } {\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(2\alpha)} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1) \Gamma(2\alpha) } {\Gamma(3\alpha+1)} \\
&= \frac{\alpha}{3\alpha} \\
&= \frac13
\end{align}